# Symfony 2 Entity Field Type not selecting existing data in edit action

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity field type I'm using in an 'edit' form.

The field type lists the correct options and the data persists, but it selects the 'top' result in the list by default, and not the data that is in the DB.

So for example if I have a record with the `shelf` marked as `SH6`, and I go to edit, the default `shelf` selected in the entity field type will be whatever is at the top of the list, ie `SH1`.

This means that users might go to edit `unitsInStock` and accidentally change the `shelf` value, because they didn't realise it was set to the wrong thing. Even more annoying is that even if you know about the problem, you may not remember the value it is supposed to be set to.

This is my controller action.

```
public function editAction($id, Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article20000stock = $em->getRepository('RegenerysQMSBundle:Article20000Stock')->find($id);
    if (!$article20000stock) {
      throw $this->createNotFoundException(
              'No id ' . $id
      );
    }

     $form = $this->createFormBuilder($article20000stock)
        ->add('article20000Information')
        ->add('unitsInStock')
        ->add('expiryDate')
        ->add('shelf', 'entity', array('class' => 'RegenerysQMSBundle:Shelf', 'property' => 'id', ))
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
       $em->flush();
     return $this->redirectToRoute('regenerys_qms_article20000stock_individual', array('id' => $id));
}

    $build['form'] = $form->createView();
    return $this->render('forms/editArticle20000Stock.html.twig', $build);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Entity was lacking a relationship, which is what was causing the issue.